# Kustomize patch with string literal: Double quotes replaced with single quotes

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kustomize

When adding a kustomize patch to a `kustomization.yaml` the double quotes are replaced with single quotes that lead to error

I am using the following:

```sh
kustomize edit add patch --patch "- op: add\n  path: /metadata/annotations/argocd.argoproj.io~1sync-wave\n. value: 1" --kind Deployment
```

is converted to

```yaml
- patch: '- op: add\n  path: /metadata/annotations/argocd.argoproj.io~1sync-wave\n value: 1'
  target:
    kind: Deployment
```

in the `kustomization.yaml`

This leads to the following error when you do `kustomize build`

```
Error: trouble configuring builtin PatchTransformer with config: `
patch: ‘- op: add\n path: /metadata/annotations/argocd.argoproj.io~1sync-wave\n  value:
  1’
target:
  kind: Deployment
`: unable to parse SM or JSON patch from [- op: add\n path: /metadata/annotations/argocd.argoproj.io~1sync-wave\n  value: 1]
```

How do I make sure that the patch in `kustomization.yaml` has double quotes instead?

Comment: why does it matter?

Comment: I have added the error. I have worked around the problem now.

Comment: I suspect if you were to specify the patch as a JSON string, which doesn't require embedded newlines, it would be easier to pass on the command line (I wouldn't do either: I would just edit `kustomization.yaml` myself rather than relying on `kustomize edit add`).

Comment: I just ended up using `kustomize edit add annotations` instead. There 100s of kustomization files so adding them manually was a bit of a pain that I was trying to avoid.

Comment: @mbbce You can post this as an answer so it'll be seen by others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I had hundreds of kustomization files that needed to be updated with the annotations for ArgoCD sync-waves, I worked around the problem by using `commonAnnotations` instead (I believe this is the right way of doing it as well). So instead of adding a patch, I did the following:

```
kustomize edit add annotation argocd.argoproj.io/sync-wave:$wave --force
```

This will add the annotation to all objects. Where `$wave` was the wave number and `--force` overwrites the annotation if it already exists in the file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case annotations were not an option, so I had to provide the patch definition serialized as an array of ops:

```
kustomize edit add patch --patch '[{"op": "replace", "path": "/spec/template/spec/containers/0/ports/0/containerPort", "value": 8080}]' --kind Deployment
```